# Unit test code := runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gin

I have created an API that is working fine, but I got an error like

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

when the unit test code is executed.

full response for your reference

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
D:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:199 (0x447473)
    panicmem: panic(memoryError)
D:/Go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:233 (0x447320)
    sigpanic: panicmem()
D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/db/teams.go:11 (0xb49b36)
    SelectAllTeams: func SelectAllTeams() (teams []models.Team, err error) {
D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/services/teams.go:11 (0xbb09ec)
    GetTeams: teams, err = db.SelectAllTeams()
D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/controllers/api.go:32 (0xbb1b51)
    ApiController.GetTeams: teams, err := services.GetTeams()
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/context.go:124 (0x9f7da1)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/middlewares/db_logger.go:72 (0xc30430)
    DBLogger.func1: c.Next()
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/context.go:124 (0x9f7da1)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/recovery.go:83 (0xa0b2ca)
    RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/context.go:124 (0x9f7da1)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/logger.go:240 (0xa0a357)
    LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/context.go:124 (0x9f7da1)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/gin.go:389 (0xa01798)
    (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
 C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.4.0/gin.go:351 (0xa00fba)
    (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
 D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/tests/controller_tests/api_test.go:73 (0xc69edd)
    (*ApiSute).TestGetArticle1: suite.Router.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
D:/Go/src/reflect/value.go:460 (0x4df3ac)
    Value.call: call(frametype, fn, args, uint32(frametype.size), uint32(retOffset))
D:/Go/src/reflect/value.go:321 (0x4deb6a)
    Value.Call: return v.call("Call", in)
C:/Users/justin.joseph/go/pkg/mod/github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.4.0/suite/suite.go:133 (0x7e0d15)
    Run.func2: method.Func.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(suite)})
D:/Go/src/testing/testing.go:909 (0x52a85f)
    tRunner: fn(t)
D:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 (0x461ab0)
    goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

My unit test code function

```
func (suite *ApiSute)  TestGetTeams() {

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/api/teams", nil)

   if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err)
       os.Exit(1)
   }
   resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
   suite.Router.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
   suite.Equal(suite.Response.Code, 200)
}
```

My model function SelectAllTeams

```
func SelectAllTeams() (teams []models.Team, err error) {
sqlStatement := `
SELECT team_uuid, name, code, description FROM cf.team`

err = DBCon.Ping()
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return
}

err = DBCon.Select(&teams, sqlStatement)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Error selecting team...")
    log.Print(err)
    return
}
return
}
```

My Db configuration and other things

```
type ApiSute struct {
    suite.Suite
    Config *viper.Viper
    Router *gin.Engine
    Response *httptest.ResponseRecorder
}


// sets up suite with dev configs and starts sets up the router
// SetupSuite runs once before executing any tests
func (suite *ApiSute) SetupSuite() {
    config.Init("dev")
    suite.Config = config.GetConfig()
    suite.Router = server.SetupRouter()
}
```

Comment: Seems like `DBCon` is `nil`, where is the code that initializes that variable?

Comment: No sir, I have configured db with viper and all, I have edited my question

Comment: Nothing in the added code shows that `DBCon` is initialized properly, and even if it is initialized by some of the delegated method calls, nothing in your question's code shows that `SetupSuite` is indeed being executed as promised in its comment... But whatever, let's say you are correct and `DBCon` is initialized as you believe, then take a look at the stacktrace, specifically the offending `.../teams.go:11` part, i.e. take a look at line `11` of the `teams.go` file, what do you see there? what code is there, can you add that to your question?

Comment: thank you fpr your comment i will check and ping you

Comment: Yes, it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `D:/Projects/GoLang/cloudfactory-backend/db/teams.go` on line `11` you refer a field from a nil-pointer. Without your complete source including the line numbers it's impossible to pinpoint, but it's probably `DBCon` not being initialized.

Comment: thank you fpr your comment i will check and ping you